# Google Sheets, formula changes when I insert rows

Tags: google-sheets

Why does my formula change, when I insert new rows into the source sheet (Formdata)?

```
=sort(Formdata!B$2:B,1,TRUE)
```

The first row in Formdata is a header.

From time to time I need to empty the Formdata sheet, but the "function" change when I start to insert new data. Example:

```
=sort(Formdata!B$31:B,1,TRUE)
```

How can I make it, so it always start from the 2nd row? (excluding row 1, the header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenneth. It is always best to share a link to a sample sheet, being sure to set permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." However, I can tell you that you're going to want your sorting formula to reference *the entire column B*, not just B2:B. Even with the $ anchor in place (i.e., B$2), when rows are added or deleted, that reference will change.

Again, I don't know how your sheet is set up. But try deleting the entire column where you currently have your formula `=sort(Formdata!B$2:B,1,TRUE)` — including the header — and place the following QUERY in the top cell of that column instead:

```
=QUERY(Formdata!B:B,"Select * Where B Is Not Null Order By B Asc",1)
```

If you want a different header for your results column than you have in your source column, just modify the end of the QUERY like this:

```
=QUERY(Formdata!B:B,"Select * Where B Is Not Null Order By B Asc Label B 'My Header'",1)
```

If you really want to stick with SORT, you can use this (again, in the top cell of a column):

```
={"My Header";SORT(FILTER(Sheet4!B:B,Sheet4!B:B<>"",ROW(Sheet4!B:B)<>1),1,TRUE)}
```

If these do not do what you expect them to do, please share an editable link to a sample sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erik. I got the query to work, or some of it. The query include the header (row 1), I dont want that. I can't delete the columns, because its a part of the connected form. Here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U13dvWPk8-hMybmhE1RKZ66y7RXXGPWt91_BNFWIup4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In cell `A2` you can use `=QUERY(Formdata!B2:B,"Select * Where B Is Not Null Order By B Asc",0)`. Make a note that we use the open range `Formdata!B2:B` instead of `Formdata!B:B`

Comment: Kenneth, I added a duplicate sheet where I placed my second formula into cell A1 and D1 (changing only the Formdata! column reference to match what you wanted). If this is not what you expect, please explain with more clarity what is not as you hoped.

Comment: Thank you very much - works exactly like I wanted, you're a champ :) So what I should have done was to add the query to the top row and adding a label to the query. Adding the last parameter ("1") to the query, tells it to skip the first row. One last question though (hope that is okay): How can I limit column A and B to only include Formdata of the last 2 entries by that person (limit by character name). Example, Jesper has made 3 form submits, but I would like to limit this to only include the latest 2. How can I do this?

Comment: Also, is there a better way to handle column E? Works but looks messy :/

Comment: Kenneth, I'm glad that the solutions I provided met the needs expressed in your post here. Please do mark the answer as "Correct/Best" for future users who are experiencing the same or similar issues. Also keeping in mind future users and that this site is designed to be streamlined, I recommend that you start a new post describing your new and separate issue regarding only including the last two submissions from any given user. As for your Column E question, please clarify what "looks messy" means.

Comment: BTW, Kenneth, I have worked out how limiting your form data to the latest two submissions per user. So I'll try to keep an eye out for your new post.

Comment: I have deleted all of your Column E formulas and replaced them with one array formula in E1, which "runs" the entire column. More efficient. =ArrayFormula({"Class";IF(D2:D="","",VLOOKUP(D2:D,Formdata!B:D,3,FALSE))})

Comment: Thank you very much. I have accepted your answer and will make a new question for the other problem :)